# Getting started with Spotipy

Tags: python, spotipy

I am completely new to spotipy, and Im wondering how to get started. I've read the 'Getting started' on https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/, and I have this code:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

scope = "user-library-read"

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope))

results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
for idx, item in enumerate(results['items']):
    track = item['track']
    print(idx, track['artists'][0]['name'], " – ", track['name'])
```

I have got the authorization, but now im wondering how to use the different functions like:

```
add_to_queue(uri, device_id=None)

current_playback(market=None, additional_types=None)
```

I tried adding the first one to my code like this:

```
add_to_queue('spotify:track:4h8vFK3v16aTsKnG1j6VCj', device_id=None)
```

But i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/andre/topp52/spotify bot.py", line 8, in <module>
    results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 1180, in current_user_saved_tracks
    return self._get("me/tracks", limit=limit, offset=offset)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 291, in _get
    return self._internal_call("GET", url, payload, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 221, in _internal_call
    headers = self._auth_headers()
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 212, in _auth_headers
    token = self.auth_manager.get_access_token(as_dict=False)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py", line 504, in get_access_token
    raise SpotifyOauthError(
spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: error: invalid_request, error_description: code must be supplied
```

I'm assuming i need to use some code in addition to the function itself.
Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
OK, so I got past the error by pasting the redirect url in the terminal, and I have found that i should use:

```
spotipy.client.Spotify.add_to_queue(self, uri, device_id=None)
```

My question now is; What do I put in the 'self' parameter? Probably a stupid question but im not sure. If i only put the song URI i get this:

```
TypeError: add_to_queue() missing 1 required positional argument: 'uri'
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sp.add_to_queue(self, uri, device_id=None)` instead of `spotipy.client.Spotify.add_to_queue`.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it :D